# What is the solution of $(m^{2}+1)^2=0?$

Tags: complex-numbers

I understand the solution of $m^{2}+1=0$ is $\iota$. However for sure this solution ($(m^{2}+1)^2=0$) should contain four roots. The answer reads $\pm \iota$ and $\pm \iota$. However I am not able to calculate all the roots. I can arrive at most up to $\pm \iota$ and cannot proceed any further.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Sometimes there are "repeated roots."  Consider what is the solution of $(m^2-1)^2=0$

Comment: Welcome to maths SX! There's no other root. There are nevertheless four roots because each  has multiplicity $2$.

Comment: Yes that is true but how do I understand/calculate them?

Comment: Technically, there are two solutions to $m^2+1=0,$ $m=i,$ or $m=-i.$

Comment: Hint: $Y^2=0$ if and only if $Y=0.$

Comment: Does $(m-1)^2=0$ have two zeros? We sometimes say it $2$ roots when we count repeated roots, but there is only one root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the factorisation which, I hope, will make you understand why there are really $4$ roots:
$$(m^2+1)^2=\bigr((m-i)(m+i)\bigl)^2=\underbrace{(m-i)}_{\text{two roots}}{}^2\underbrace{(m+i)}_{\text{two roots}}{}^2.$$
You have $4$ factors, which are equal in pairs.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $(m^2+1)^2=(m^2+1)(m^2+1)=(m+i)(m-i)(m+i)(m-i)$

Answer (score 0):

Why should it have four roots ? A $4-$degree polynomial has **at most** four distinct roots...

Here $(m^2+1)^2=0$ implies that $m^2+1=0$, then you have $m=i$ or $m=-i$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is obtained by solving $m^{2} + 1 = 0$ which yields $m = \pm i$.

That being said, you have effectively a quartic equation which will have exactly four roots counting multiplicities (repititions).

Here, $-i$ and $i$ are the two distinct solutions, each having multiplicity two.